# Prevent horizontal touch pad scrolling on macbooks using Chrome?

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, scroll

I would like to prevent horizontal scrolling on my site using the multitouch trackpad on Macbooks, magical mouse etc. This issue is solved for Firefox (using solution from here: [Prevent horizontal touch pad scrolling on macbooks using Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872229/prevent-horizontal-touch-pad-scrolling-on-macbooks-using-firefox)). But it still gives me trouble on Chrome.

Is there any way of preventing this functionality on Chrome (e.g. using eventlistener)? Thanks

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737709/any-way-to-prevent-horizontal-scrolling-triggering-swipe-back-gesture-on-os-x-li

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and setting `overflow` to `hidden` in the CSS did not work too. My  solution was using:

```
jQuery('html, body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
```

I dont know why, but in JavaScript it works.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you can use `overflow-x: hidden;` to prevent scrolling. If you apply it to the body, or another element specifically that should do the trick.

Comment: Alternately you could do it through JQuery if you prefer. $(element).css('overflow', 'hidden')